# How do I get rid of strikethrough?

Tags: r, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, statet

I am using Eclipse and StatET as my IDE for R. In this version, it adds strikethrough to special characters such as `,` and `<`. How do I get rid of this strikethrough?

I have looked in Preferences > StatET > Source Editors and no luck so far.

Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

OS: Mac OSX Seirra

Other add-ons: Eclipse colour theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the strikethrough culprits in `Preferences > StatET > Source Editors > R Syntax Highlighting`

In the Elements list box, I had to click through every item and weed out the checked "Strikethrough" options as they appeared. Many elements to weed through.